# Synonymise tags such that [numerals] and [zahlen] are both mapped to [numbers]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I just noted that we have a [numbers](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/numbers) as well as a [numerals](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/numerals) tag, which should be synonymised somehow since their coverage is almost identical.

Now, *numbers* has a slightly broader scope than *numerals,* e.g., [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/2984/2594) is not about numbers but not about numerals. Therefore, I think the final tag should be *numbers.* However, I cannot suggest a synonym *numerals → numbers* as there already is the synonym *zahlen → numerals.* Hence, this is probably best done by a moderator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreed that having only one tag to cover questions on numbers or numerals should exist.

The tag [numerals](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/numerals) is now merged to [numbers](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/numbers) with [numerals](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/numerals) being a synonym to [numbers](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/numbers) in analogy to English Stackexchange.